# Convert double binding to double value in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, javafx-2, javafx-8

This is my code. I want to store this total value into database

How can I do that? If I directly assign to double variable it shows error:

> double binding value cannot converted into double

```
DoubleBinding total = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
supplytable.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(conductor::getPrice)),
                                 supplytable.getItems());
lbltotal.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Total: %.2f", total));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example [`getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleExpression.html#getValue%28%29) or [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleExpression.html#doubleValue%28%29) method of `DoubleBinding`:

```
double doubleValue = total.doubleValue();
Double value = total.getValue();
```